# How can you "global replace" in Crystal without visual studio?

Tags: replace, crystal-reports

I had to replace a DB table with embedded SQL in Crystal.
Now I find myself completely amazed that (apparently) I have to open thirty or more formulas one at a time and replace the table name with "Command"

If I select "All formulas" in the replace widget, all the replace controls are disabled.

This is so stupid that I figure I am missing something.

I am working the Crystal files directly in the Crystal IDE.  Not able to fire up a C# or VB program to do it for me.  I did try a couple of times in the past to edit things in Crystal files with regexp/perl/editors and similar, but that failed due to the Crystal file format.

*(S.O. says my question "appears subjective and is likely to be closed."  Huh?)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transitioning from linked tables (Database 'expert') to a `command` (or the other direction) has always been painful (I've been using the product since v4)--CR doesn't have a good (or even mediocre) way to do this.  You should be able to map your `command` to a single table, but you'll lose field (from the canvas) during the process (because CR will remove unmapped fields).  Best practice is to always use a `command` or to wrap each table.field element in a formula field.

With earlier version of the product, I might have suggested using the SDK to make the change.  However, this level of control has been shifted to BusinessObjects' RAS SDK.

If you are interested, have a look at my [RptToXml](http://code.google.com/p/rpttoxml/) project or its [C# replacement](https://github.com/ajryan/RptToXml).

Comment: Unfortunately, wrapping the fields in formulas isn't an option when you have to "fix" a report written elsewhere.  And even on our own reports, Crystal disables the replace option when you change the scope to "all formulas" (so we still have to open one formula at a time and paste).

Comment: Thanks for the project link though--although I don't have Visual Studio now, I have requested it, and if you hadn't mentioned it, something similar eould have been high on my list!